# Passing around complete objects when applying CQRS/ES

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

Through the research I've done into implementing CQRS/ES (I'm aware that they aren't necessarily tied to each other), I haven't yet seen a full object passed to a command.

For example, why shouldn't I take in the parameters for a *bug* in a bug-tracking API like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateBug([FromBody] Bug bug)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400);
    } else
    {
        commandHandler.Handle(new OpenBug(bug));

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(201);
    }
}
```

Where *OpenBug* is the command:

```
public class OpenBug : ICommand
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Models.Bug NewBug { get; set; }

    public OpenBug(Models.Bug bug) {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        NewBug = bug;

        //Create BugOpened Event here (and add to event sequence?)
    }
}
```

From what I've seen, it's handled more often like this:

```
commandHandler.Handle(new OpenBug(bug.Description, bug.Fixed));
```

And then constructed elsewhere.

Is there a specific reason for this? Surely, I'm missing something here or doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Bug` is a complex class with various properties or fields, each of these custom types with other properties and fields, etc., you'd be putting quite a burden on the client to supply that entire object graph just to open a bug.

You can apply [Postel's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) here: if all you need to open a bug is for example a bug *ID*, anything else puts an unwarranted constraint on the client. You'd be making the API harder to use. That doesn't fit the CQRS ideal of **task-based UIs**.

In [a white paper that sometimes can be hard to find on the internet](https://cqrs.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/cqrs_documents.pdf), Greg Young explains the problem of transmitting big DTOs back and forth between application tiers.

Comment: Thanks for that. It makes a whole lot of sense, looking at it that way.